# OpenCV code doesn't work on specific image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to run the followin code (based on [this page](https://answers.opencv.org/question/25912/split-contours-into-many-small-rectangles/)) on an image, but it doesn't work:

```c
Mat src=imread("img.jpg",1);
Mat tmp,thr;
cvtColor(src,tmp,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(tmp,thr,200,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);

vector< vector <Point> > contours;
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0));//Ceate Mat to draw contour

int box_w=10; // Define box width here
int box_h=10; // Define box height here
int threshold_perc=25; //perceantage value for eliminating the box according to pixel count inside the box
int threshold=(box_w*box_h*threshold_perc)/100; 

findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); //Find contour

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){ 
 drawContours( dst,contours, i, Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy ); // Draw contour with  thickness = filled 
 Rect r= boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find bounding rect

// Scan the image with in bounding box  
for(int j=r.x;j<r.x+r.width;j=j+box_w){
  for(int k=r.y;k<r.y+r.height;k=k+box_h){
    Rect roi_rect(j,k,box_w,box_h);
    Mat roi = dst(roi_rect);
    int count = countNonZero(roi);
    if(count > threshold)
      rectangle(src, roi_rect, Scalar(255,0,0),1,8,0 );         
    }
  }
 }
imshow("src",src);
waitKey();
```

It works fine for any normal image, but for the images below, it either breaks or doesn't find the contour and draws boxes all over the image.

[image]
[image]

It says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9A72DA388 in test2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000FECC9DEAC0.

It breaks and points to here:

```c
inline
Mat Mat::operator()( const Rect& roi ) const
{
    return Mat(*this, roi);
}
```

in **[mat.inl.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L877)**.

What is wrong with my image? I have changed it from Gray-scale to RGB, but didn't help.

On the following image, it works fine:
[image]

Comment: Your code opens a PNG image. The images you show that don't work are JPEGs. Please make your question consistent with itself.

Comment: Have you debugged the program? Does the Exception throw any message? A common problem would be the corner case where you try to access pixels outside the image, by adding the fixed size to the coordinates, which would also explain why the last image doesn't have this problem.

Comment: "What is wrong with my image?" - Nothing. Something is wrong with your *code processing the image*. No image should *ever* cause a crash. If it does, you are doing something wrong and you should focus on fixing the bug in *your code* that causes it to crash on certain images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The image can be PNG or JPEG. I tried different formats.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the code is easy to test. Just try the code with the images I posted and you can see just by changing the image, the program breaks with the message I posted in the bottom of the question.

Comment: @JoelFilho I didn't change the code. Just by changing the input image, the program breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you're trying to access a region of the image that doesn't exist by using a rectangle of fixed size.

By intersecting the roi with the rectangle, you can avoid this problem:

```cpp
Mat roi = dst(roi_rect & r);
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what was the reason of down-vote though!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in the first images, the contour gets close to the boundaries of the image and in the bottom `for loop` of the program, it exceeds the coordinates. It was fixed with this:

```c
// Scan the image with in bounding box  
        for (int j = r.x;j<r.x + r.width;j = j + box_w) {
            for (int k = r.y;k<r.y + r.height;k = k + box_h) {
                Rect roi_rect(j, k, box_w, box_h);
                if (j + box_w < dst.cols && k + box_h < dst.rows)
                {
                    Mat roi = dst(roi_rect);
                    int count = countNonZero(roi);
                    if (count > threshold)
                        rectangle(src, roi_rect, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]